# Django Cookiecutter Moving Template folder up one level

Tags: templates, config, cookiecutter-django

I want to move the templates folder up one level and out of the {{cookiecutter.project_slug}} folder.

I can use this and it works locally but I know it is not correct:

```
str ( ROOT_DIR + 'templates' )
```

what is the proper way to format this DIRS?

Here is what Django Cookiecutter uses:

```
ROOT_DIR = environ.Path ( __file__ ) - 3  
APPS_DIR = ROOT_DIR.path ( 'myapp' )

TEMPLATES = [
   {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        str(APPS_DIR.path('templates')),
    ],

    },
 },
]
```

https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% certain, but it seems to work. Just added another os.path.dirname() to the DIR.

I created a BASE_DIR like a normal Django project then put it into the TEMPLATES.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname ( os.path.dirname ( os.path.dirname ( os.path.abspath ( __file__ ) ) ) )


TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS'   : [
        str ( os.path.join ( BASE_DIR, 'templates' ) ),
    ],
}
```

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        str(ROOT_DIR.path('templates'))
    ],
}
```

But why do you need to break the suggested structure?

Comment: just think it is a pain to have it buried down the extra level.  I like to see the templates with all my apps. seems easier for me.  I hope it is ok?  thanks.